# Code Signing issue when Archiving using Fastlane in Github actions

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, github-actions, fastlane

Recently we have migrated all of our iOS projects from GitLab to GitHub. However when we are trying to build the code using GitHub
Actions(Fastlane) In our self-hosted runners it keeps falling with error mentioned below.

When building(***gym***) the project it signs with correct certificates and profiles but when archiving it somehow uses the development certificate to sign the pods.

**Command Executed:**

```
set -o pipefail && xcodebuild -workspace ./{ProjectName}.xcworkspace -scheme UAT -destination 'generic/platform=iOS' -archivePath /Users/{user}/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives/2022-05-03/{ProjectName}\ 2022-05-03\ 16.13.00.xcarchive -allowProvisioningUpdates clean archive | tee /Users/{user}/Library/Logs/gym/{ProjectName}-UAT.log | xcpretty
```

*Note: It used to archive fine with Gitlab pipelines. Also, it builds fine when the commands are run manually on the hosted runner.*

[image: Code signing issue]

[image: Archive failed error]

iOS: macOS Big Sur 11.6

XCode: 13.0 and 13.2.1

What we've tried:

- Locking and Unlocking keychain.
- Re-creation and re-installing certificates
- Upgrading Ruby
- Running on different machines(We have 2 runners)
- Restarting and Cleaning the runners
- Deintegrated and Integrated pods.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to pod install? The error indicates a problem with ur build phases script added by Cocoapods. maybe deintegrate and integrate Cocoapods again.

Comment: Yeah, tried it. Didn't work.